# Are there jungles in xbox 360 edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I’ve made just about every food in the game except for a cookie. It says I need coca beans but I read online that cocoa beans are only in the Jungle, AND THEN I read that finding a jungle is VERY RARE. I’ve scoured not only through my own world but through other worlds (in creative mode) (to see if they are actually possible in the Xbox 360-I didn’t find it) it also says melons are only found in the jungle too, which sucks. 
My question is, are jungle biomes around in the Minecraft version of the xbox360? It’s the FIRST edition of the game not the story mode or anything. Also, I have no idea how the seed generator works, nor do I want to use it- nor do I think I can, I don’t have internet. I just want to know if jungles are even in the game so I won’t go looking for something that isn’t there.

Answer (score 2):

Jungle biomes are in the Xbox 360 edition of Minecraft, but the problem is that they are quite rare, the easiest way to find a jungle is by using seed picker when making a world, (which is the arrow facing left at the right end of the seed thing) and choosing epic jungle.